# HTML5 conversion for powerpoint

Tags: html, vba, powerpoint

Is it possible to use macro's in a PowerPoint presentation that has been converted to a HTML5 package?

Comment: It might be possible to write a JavaScript equivalent of the Macro, but that would be an entirely new piece of code

Answer (score 1):

No.  Macros = Visual Basic for Applications, a programming language that's not supported in HTML.  Even if it were, the code would be designed to act on the shapes and other objects in a PowerPoint presentation; you'd be running it in a web page.  A bit like trying to follow a recipe for spaghetti & meatballs using the ingredients you'd find in an automobile mechanic's toolchest.  ;-)